# spring security deny all a part of resources

Tags: spring-security, wicket

I am using spring-security-3.1 with wicket
I want to deny all request and redirect them to to login 
a part of /resources/* where there are photoes and my ajax loader 
what i am doing today is :

```
<security:http create-session="always" use-expressions="true">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"
        access="permitAll()" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/"
        access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login" />
    <security:anonymous enabled="true" />
    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" />

</security:http>
```

I am getting in the client this error :

```
GET http://localhost:8080/myServer/resources/images/ajax-loader.gif 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was else where , this is a vaild situation in the pattern I wrote above

```
 http://localhost:8080/myServer/resources/images/ajax-loader.gif
```